# Can I deploy .NET server object extension to a linux box hosting ArcGIS Server 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-server, .net, linux, server-object-extension

We have developed a server object extension in Visual Studio 2010, and successfully deployed to the ArcGIS Server hosted on a windows box. However, when we try to deploy it to a linux server, it complains that the DLL is not found in the .SOE file, which actually contains. Is it possible to deploy a .NET SOE on a linux box? If so, what's the steps to deploy it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

.NET SOEs will not run on Linux. You will have to recreate it in Java or C++: [ArcObjects SDK 10.2 system requirements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/#/ArcObjects_SDK/01510000006n000000/)

See this [blog post](http://ericsgisblog.blogspot.com/2013/04/porting-arcgis-server-object-extension.html) on porting .NET SOEs to Java.

Answer (score 1):

One note on SOE deployment:

I now deploy all my SOEs using python through the ArcGIS REST Admin API using Python.  Its awesome because I can deploy my SOE to several machines at once.  I just stick a soe_deploy.py file in each of my projects:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 

    from ags_servers import servers
    from soe_utils import *

    soePath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'BatchIdentifyRESTSOE101','bin','Debug', 'BatchIdentifyRESTSOE101.soe')

    #Register on Staging
    server = servers.get('staging_arcgis_service_name')
    upload(server['server'],server['port'], server['adminUser'], server['adminPass'], soePath)
    # stopStartServices(server['server'],server['port'], server['adminUser'], server['adminPass'],'Stop',[r'serviceFolder/serviceUsingSOE.MapServer'])
    # stopStartServices(server['server'],server['port'], server['adminUser'], server['adminPass'],'Start',[r'serviceFolder/serviceUsingSOE.MapServer'])

    #Register on Production
    server = servers.get('production_arcgis_service_name')
    upload(server['server'],server['port'], server['adminUser'], server['adminPass'], soePath)
   # stopStartServices(server['server'],server['port'], server['adminUser'], server['adminPass'],'Stop',[r'serviceFolder/serviceUsingSOE.MapServer'])
   # stopStartServices(server['server'],server['port'], server['adminUser'], server['adminPass'],'Start',[r'serviceFolder/serviceUsingSOE.MapServer'])
```

The ags_servers module contains a dictionary of server names to server details / credentials.  I posted a quick gist of the soe_utils.py file, with some of my custom decorators / logging removed.  You will need to test, but the meat is there.

https://gist.github.com/brendancol/7029764

**Note:** there are some security issue with the setup.

1. Credentials are stored in the ags_servers module which is dangerous
2. The soe_utils is passing the credentials over http as plain text which could be sniffed and stolen.  These are two items I want to fix.

Definitely checkout the ArcGIS Server Administrator toolkit which includes a sample on deploying a registering an SOE.
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=12dde73e0e784e47818162b4d41ee340